# bluetooth module accelerometer

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a project to do for school: a captor for boxer. It will be
i have to connect an Arduino nano 33 ble Sense with the Bluetooth.
The idea is to transfer data of accelerometer to a smartphone with an application (maybe made with MIT app Inventor).
And so show to an athlete the power of his hit with the application (accelration --) force ---) power).
But i didn't manage to connect my arduino to my smarthphone. Indeed, i follow a tuto to connect it. In fact, I succeed in connecting the arduino with nFr connect but I can't do anything.

the code (for bluetooth nFr connect) in question is here : (its just an example because my final goal is to do this but with the accelerometer)

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>

BLEService dataService("180C"); // User defined service

BLEStringCharacteristic dataCharacteristic("2A56", // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify, 13); // remote clients will be able to read and subscribe to notifications

int oldValue = 0;  // last value
long previousMillis = 0;  // last time the value was checked, in ms

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication
    while (!Serial)
        ;

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // initialize the built-in LED pin

    if (!BLE.begin()) { // initialize BLE
        Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    BLE.setLocalName("Sac de frappe"); // Set name for connection
    BLE.setAdvertisedService(dataService); // Advertise service
    dataService.addCharacteristic(dataCharacteristic); // Add characteristic to service
    BLE.addService(dataService); // Add service
    dataCharacteristic.setValue(String(oldValue)); // Set data string

    BLE.advertise(); // Start advertising
    Serial.print("Peripheral device MAC: ");
    Serial.println(BLE.address());
    Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Started");

  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.print("Accelerometer sample rate = ");
  Serial.print(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
  Serial.println(" Hz");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Acceleration in G's");
  Serial.println("X\tY\tZ");
}

void loop()
{
    BLEDevice central = BLE.central(); // Wait for a BLE central to connect

    // if a central is connected to the peripheral:
    if (central) {
        Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
        // print the central's BT address:
        Serial.println(central.address());
        // turn on the LED to indicate the connection:
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

        // update value every 200ms
        // while the central is connected:
        while (central.connected()) {
            long currentMillis = millis();
            // if 200ms have passed, update value:
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
                previousMillis = currentMillis;
                updateValue();
            }
        }
    }
    // when the central disconnects, turn off the LED:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("Disconnected from central MAC: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
     float x, y, z;

  if (IMU.accelerationAvailable()) {
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z);

    Serial.print(x);
    Serial.print('\t');
    Serial.print(y);
    Serial.print('\t');
    Serial.println(z);
  }

}

void updateValue() {
    int value = analogRead(A0); // Read your accelerometer data here

    if (value != oldValue) {
        Serial.print("Accelerometer Data is now: "); // print it
        Serial.println(value);
        dataCharacteristic.writeValue(String(value));  // update value
        // save the level for next comparison
        oldValue = value;
    }
}
```

thanks for helping (sorry for my english)

Comment: post code in question.

Comment: Please copy the code to your question, do not use images

Comment: yes okay sorry i will add that now

Comment: You said you can connect to the service using nRF Connect but cant do anything? Can you describe what you mean by that? Your code looks like you should be able to read from the characteristic

Comment: yes but i want to transfer the acceleration measured by the accelerometer inside the arduino and display it on a simple smartphone application via bluetooth

Comment: I understand, but are you able to read "Hello World" using nRF Connect?

Comment: yes i see Hello World indeed

Comment: You said you did not manage to connect your smartphone. but can read the message, so you did connect. What exactly is your problem? You want to use your own app and don't know what to do?

Comment: yes exactly because this code was just a test to try to connect bluetooth but i did'nt manage to transfer the measurements of the accelrometer of the arduino to my mobile phone... (the final goal will to have my own app to display this data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to match edited code in question**

To transfer your accelerometer data you could do something similar to the [BatteryMonitor example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/blob/master/examples/Peripheral/BatteryMonitor/BatteryMonitor.ino):

Use notifications on your characteristic to allow your smartphone to    receive changes without constantly reading manually. Readout and    update accelerometer data constantly while central is connected.

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>

BLEService dataService("180C"); // User defined service

BLEStringCharacteristic dataCharacteristic("2A56", // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify, 50); // remote clients will be able to read and subscribe to notifications

float oldX = 0.0;  // last value
float oldY = 0.0;
float oldZ = 0.0;
long previousMillis = 0;  // last time the value was checked, in ms

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication
    while (!Serial)
        ;

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // initialize the built-in LED pin

    if (!BLE.begin()) { // initialize BLE
        Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    BLE.setLocalName("Sac de frappe"); // Set name for connection
    BLE.setAdvertisedService(dataService); // Advertise service
    dataService.addCharacteristic(dataCharacteristic); // Add characteristic to service
    BLE.addService(dataService); // Add service
    dataCharacteristic.setValue(""); // Set initial value

    BLE.advertise(); // Start advertising
    Serial.print("Peripheral device MAC: ");
    Serial.println(BLE.address());
    Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println("Started");

    if (!IMU.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
        while (1);
    }

    Serial.print("Accelerometer sample rate = ");
    Serial.print(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
    Serial.println(" Hz");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Acceleration in G's");
    Serial.println("X\tY\tZ");
}

void loop()
{
    BLEDevice central = BLE.central(); // Wait for a BLE central to connect

    // if a central is connected to the peripheral:
    if (central) {
        Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
        // print the central's BT address:
        Serial.println(central.address());
        // turn on the LED to indicate the connection:
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

        // update value every 200ms
        // while the central is connected:
        while (central.connected()) {
            long currentMillis = millis();
            // if 200ms have passed, update value:
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
                previousMillis = currentMillis;
                updateValue();
            }
        }
    }
    // when the central disconnects, turn off the LED:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("Disconnected from central MAC: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
}

void updateValue() {
    float x, y, z;

    if (!IMU.accelerationAvailable()) return; // Return if not ready
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z); // Read new data

    if (x != oldX || y != oldY || z != oldZ) {
        // print it
        Serial.print(x);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(y);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.println(z);
        dataCharacteristic.writeValue("X: " + String(x) + " Y: " + String(y) + " Z: " + String(z));  // update value
        // save the value for next comparison
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;
        oldZ = z;
    }
}
```

You can validate the functionality using nRF Connect. If everything works how you like it proceed to develop you own app.

Comment: How am i supposed to validate functionality using nRF connect ? and if i do that it will always pairing (link) my phone to the arduino via bluetooth and so allow me to create my own application EDIT : it do not work because of the line "        dataCharacteristic.writeValue(value);  // update value" it put string ambigous ...

Comment: @Faiz42 it is always a bad idea to develop your app and your peripheral at the same time. There would be no way of telling which side is causing an error. Start by developing you peripheral and use nRF Connect to test your device by reading and writing. If everything works on the peripheral side you can start developing your app.

Comment: I eddited my answer to write the new Value as a String. You can use other datatypes for your characteristic if you want, I don't know what you need and what datatype your sensor returns

Comment: ok thanks last question : if i want to connect simply the arduino to my phone like a classic bluetooth device , how i suppose to do that ? because with this program i can't pairing my smartphone to the arduino i have a message on my phone "application is needed to use this device" ....

Comment: Exactly. If you want to use a Bluetooth Low Energy Device you have to use an app like nRF Connect or your own custom one. Connecting to a Bluetooth device through the settings of your smartphone is only possible using Bluetooth Classic. This would allow you a serial connection but you would most certainly need a custom app as well since you are sending custom data and are not using one of the default profiles like the one used for a Bluetooth Headset

Comment: ok i see but im a beginner in arduino .. how i suppose ton build a code to activate bluetooth and transfered data to my phone .. ?

Comment: Maybe you should start with a smaller project and get used to the arduino environment first

Comment: it's for school i have to to that... can you give me a code which can permit this please ?

Comment: For your arduino or for your phone?

Comment: for my arduino  (33 ble sense) in order to connect it to my phone

Comment: I gave you the Code for your arduino in my answer. You have to add some code to read the accelerometer yourself. You will find many examples online depending on the type of sensor you are using. You will not find an example that combines both parts, but you should be able to connect them

Comment: I have edited my first post with my new code including the accelerometer...  How am i suppose to do nowto read the data of accelerometer ? and transform it into power (F=m*acc)  because i just read some number on nrf connect but not the values of my accelerometer ...  really thanks you for helping me

Comment: @Faiz42 I edited my answer. I just moved your added lines into the updateValue() method

Comment: dataCharacteristic.setValue(String(oldValue)); // Set data string  this line do no work ...  maybe if i put dataCharacteristic.setValue(String(oldX)(String(oldY) String(oldZ)); // Set data string    ??  because i don't really undestrand  what is this line for ?

Comment: and also i have the  error message " expression cannot be used as a function" for this line :dataCharacteristic.writeValue("X: " (String(x)) " Y: " (String(y)) " Z: " (String(z))); i try to do without the "+" but same message with more "(" but same ...

Comment: @Faiz42 I corrected my earlier mistakes. I have not tested this code since I don't have your accelerometer on me. If some things don't work please ask a new question for this specific problem. I hope you achieve your goals, but I can't do your project for you