# error message in order to connect arduino in bluetooth

Tags: error-handling, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

(sorry for bad english)

I try to display the accelerometer data (x,y,z) from my arduino (33 ble sense) to my phone via bluetooth.
This is a project for school : it will be a hit captor for a boxer (put on a punching bag). Indeed, it will save the acceleration of the punching bag to finally convert it into "power" of hit .
To finally manage to convert this data into power of an athlete (a boxer) maybe with a function include in the programm later (F=m x acc).
I start with nrF connect for the beggining but i have to create a app with "MIT app inventor" later..

but now my code do not work. My code is here :

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>

BLEService dataService("180C"); // User defined service

BLEStringCharacteristic dataCharacteristic("2A56", // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify, 50); // remote clients will be able to read and subscribe to notifications

float oldX = 0.0;  // last value
float oldY = 0.0;
float oldZ = 0.0;
long previousMillis = 0;  // last time the value was checked, in ms

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication
    while (!Serial)
        ;

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // initialize the built-in LED pin

    if (!BLE.begin()) { // initialize BLE
        Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    BLE.setLocalName("Sac de frappe"); // Set name for connection
    BLE.setAdvertisedService(dataService); // Advertise service
    dataService.addCharacteristic(dataCharacteristic); // Add characteristic to service
    BLE.addService(dataService); // Add service
    dataCharacteristic.setValue(String(oldX)); // Set data string

    BLE.advertise(); // Start advertising
    Serial.print("Peripheral device MAC: ");
    Serial.println(BLE.address());
    Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println("Started");

    if (!IMU.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
        while (1);
    }

    Serial.print("Accelerometer sample rate = ");
    Serial.print(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
    Serial.println(" Hz");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Acceleration in G's");
    Serial.println("X\tY\tZ");
}

void loop()
{
    BLEDevice central = BLE.central(); // Wait for a BLE central to connect

    // if a central is connected to the peripheral:
    if (central) {
        Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
        // print the central's BT address:
        Serial.println(central.address());
        // turn on the LED to indicate the connection:
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

        // update value every 200ms
        // while the central is connected:
        while (central.connected()) {
            long currentMillis = millis();
            // if 200ms have passed, update value:
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
                previousMillis = currentMillis;
                updateValue();
            }
        }
    }
    // when the central disconnects, turn off the LED:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("Disconnected from central MAC: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
}

void updateValue() {
    float x, y, z;

    if (!IMU.accelerationAvailable()) return; // Return if not ready
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z); // Read new data

    if (x != oldX || y != oldY || z != oldZ) {
        // print it
        Serial.print(x);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(y);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.println(z);
        dataCharacteristic.writeValue("X: " + (String(x)) + " Y: " (String(y)) + " Z: " + (String(z)));  // update value
        // save the value for next comparison
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;
        oldZ = z;
    }
}
```

I have an error message : expression cannot be used as a function ... about this line : (void updateValue):

```
dataCharacteristic.writeValue("X: " + (String(x)) + " Y: " (String(y)) + " Z: " + (String(z)));  // update value
```

and also in this line : (void setup)

```
dataCharacteristic.setValue(String(oldX)); // Set data string
```

How am i suppose to put the three value x, y and z ?

I can't fix it ... can you help me please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed my two mistakes in my answer to your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66653891/bluetooth-module-accelerometer)

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>

BLEService dataService("180C"); // User defined service

BLEStringCharacteristic dataCharacteristic("2A56", // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify, 50); // remote clients will be able to read and subscribe to notifications

float oldX = 0.0;  // last value
float oldY = 0.0;
float oldZ = 0.0;
long previousMillis = 0;  // last time the value was checked, in ms

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communication
    while (!Serial)
        ;

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // initialize the built-in LED pin

    if (!BLE.begin()) { // initialize BLE
        Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    BLE.setLocalName("Sac de frappe"); // Set name for connection
    BLE.setAdvertisedService(dataService); // Advertise service
    dataService.addCharacteristic(dataCharacteristic); // Add characteristic to service
    BLE.addService(dataService); // Add service
    dataCharacteristic.setValue(""); // Set initial value

    BLE.advertise(); // Start advertising
    Serial.print("Peripheral device MAC: ");
    Serial.println(BLE.address());
    Serial.println("Waiting for connections...");

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println("Started");

    if (!IMU.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
        while (1);
    }

    Serial.print("Accelerometer sample rate = ");
    Serial.print(IMU.accelerationSampleRate());
    Serial.println(" Hz");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Acceleration in G's");
    Serial.println("X\tY\tZ");
}

void loop()
{
    BLEDevice central = BLE.central(); // Wait for a BLE central to connect

    // if a central is connected to the peripheral:
    if (central) {
        Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
        // print the central's BT address:
        Serial.println(central.address());
        // turn on the LED to indicate the connection:
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

        // update value every 200ms
        // while the central is connected:
        while (central.connected()) {
            long currentMillis = millis();
            // if 200ms have passed, update value:
            if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
                previousMillis = currentMillis;
                updateValue();
            }
        }
    }
    // when the central disconnects, turn off the LED:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    Serial.print("Disconnected from central MAC: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
}

void updateValue() {
    float x, y, z;

    if (!IMU.accelerationAvailable()) return; // Return if not ready
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z); // Read new data

    if (x != oldX || y != oldY || z != oldZ) {
        // print it
        Serial.print(x);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(y);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.println(z);
        dataCharacteristic.writeValue("X: " + String(x) + " Y: " + String(y) + " Z: " + String(z));  // update value
        // save the value for next comparison
        oldX = x;
        oldY = y;
        oldZ = z;
    }
}
```